# How to replace row value with only the integers within the value using Pandas?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, dataframe

I have a bunch of columns like this

```
District
________
State District 1
State District 2
State District 3
4th State House District
5th State House District
State District 6
...
State District 17
```

I want to transform each of these so it only contains the integer value:

```
District
________
1
2
3
4
5
6
...
17
```

How can this be done with Pandas? Is this even possible with Pandas or would I have to perform this transformation with SQL or some database language?

Comment: Likey a regex solution : ``df.District.str.extract(r"(\d+)")``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution using `str.replace` would be to just strip off all non numeric characters:

```py
df['District'] = df['District'].str.replace('\D', '')
```